# Use Case Apache Spark getting Nameerror running a line with countryCodeMap

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm very new to this and I'm using a use case found on databricks.com to learn more. (https://databricks.com/blog/2018/07/09/analyze-games-from-european-soccer-leagues-with-apache-spark-and-databricks.html)

I'm running spark through Jupiter notebook and python 3. I have been able to load the files etc but I'm getting a nameError for on of the lines. it says it has not been defined, but I can't see anywhere where to define it or how to do that.
 the line is this:

```
gameInfDf = gameInfDf.withColumn("country_code", mapKeyToVal(countryCodeMap) ("country"))
```

the nameError is: name 'countryCodeMap' is not defined
before this I ran this code chunk:

```
def mapKeyToVal(mapping):
    def mapKeyToVal_(col):
        return mapping.get(col)
    return udf(mapKeyToVal_, StringType())
```

Can please someone tell me if I'm running it on the wrong program or what my problem is?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://databricks.com/blog/2018/07/09/analyze-games-from-european-soccer-leagues-with-apache-spark-and-databricks.html. You missed the space in your return. Not sure how you were able to run this part. I get an error when I try to define the UDF. 
Try this:

```
def mapKeyToVal(mapping):
    def mapKeyToVal_(col):
        return mapping.get(col)
    return udf(mapKeyToVal_, StringType())
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out@AnishNair. This is unfortunately not the error, just me being a little too fast typing the code into my post. I'm still getting an error on the next line, where countrycode is not defined..